# Spring Boot Controller integration test for csv file reading?

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv, testing, integration-testing

I have some endpoints used only reading data from CSV file via OpenCSV and now I am trying to write Integration Test (for Controller methods) for this app (I already wrote Unit Tests).

I could not find a proper example for Integration test, so how should I write Integration test for my endpoints? I think maybe I should provide example CSV file instead of mocking, but really no experience for that.

I am also thinking that, normally to test an endpoint that creates data on dB, we use H2, etc embedded database with the same data models and repositories. In this case, should I use the same CSV template with mock data and then check the read data? I am not sure if it is a good idea for Integration Test of CSV file reading.

Any help would really be appreciated, I just need you valuable suggestions.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is too general and too broad to be answered in a reliable way. Based on what you wrote, it's difficult to tell: "Do this or that".
It looks like reading up on Spring Boot testing (in SB docs) might be a good start; perhaps frameworks for controller testing like RestAssured could at least provide you with some inspiration.

Comment: I read them and there is nothing special. So, I just need to follow from the most suitable path. Any idea?